# How to count bigrams in several inputs in python

Tags: python

Before I start, here are the exact instruction from my learning material (Grok Learning, Python)
"Write a program to read in multiple lines of input from the user, where each line is a space-separated sentence of words. Your program should then count up how many times each of the bigrams occur across all input sentences. The bigrams should be treated in a case insensitive manner by converting the input lines to lowercase. Once the user stops entering input, your program should print out each of the bigrams that appear more than once, along with their corresponding frequencies."

I am supposed to find the bigrams within several inputs and I have formulated this code. This code works by asking for inputs until the input is blank, then adding that whole line into a list called combined, where it is converted into bigrams in this format [('this', 'is'), ('is', 'a')] which equals to the list called text. Now that list called text is converted into simple bigrams in this format [('this is'), ('is a')] into another list called newlist. Then I add all repeating strings into a dictionary called my_dict and add them. I print them out in separate lines so it can produce each bigram and how frequent it is, discluding bigrams that only occur once. Here is my code:

```
newlist = []
combined = []
a = (input("Line: ")).lower()
while a:
  combined.append(a)
  text = [b for l in combined for b in zip(l.split(" ")[:-1], l.split(" ")[1:])]
  a = (input("Line: ")).lower()
for bigram in text:
  newbigram = ' '.join(bigram)
  newlist.append(newbigram)
my_dict = {i:newlist.count(i) for i in newlist}
for words in sorted(my_dict):
  if my_dict[words] > 1:
    print(str(words) + str(": ") + str(my_dict[words]))
```

Here is my output:

```
Line: The big red ball
Line: The big red ball is near the big red box
Line: I am near the box
Line: 
big red: 3
near the: 2
red ball: 2
the big: 3
```

See this code worked fine, but whenever I set an empty a value, it comes with this error message:

```
Line: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "program.py", line 8, in <module>
    for bigram in text:
NameError: name 'text' is not defined
```

Why is this the case and how can i fix it?

Comment: An empty string is not _truthy_. Therefore you don't go into your `while` loop and define `text`

Comment: Hint: When `a` is empty, how many times will the `while a:` block (including the `text = ...` statement) run?

Comment: Use `text = []` at the beginning. So `text` is defined in either case where you have value or when you set an empty value.

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is due to the fact that *empty* input actually contains a value of `\n`, thus your `while` statement evaluates as `True`. You can strip the user input so that you don't include trailing/leading whitespace as it is inconsequential for your use anyway, e.g.:

```
a = input("Line: ").strip().lower()
```

And if the user never enters anything (only a blank line) your `text` list will never be initialized so initialize it before your `while` loop.

That being said, you're overcomplicating this - all you need is a dictionary counter and to iterate over tuples of your input to increase the count, e.g.:

```
import collections

counter = collections.defaultdict(int)  # use a dictionary factory to speed up our counting
while True:
    line = input("Line: ").lower().split()  # lowercase and split on whitespace
    if not line:  # user entered an empty line
        break
    for bigram in zip(line, line[1:]):  # iterate over bigrams
        counter[bigram] += 1  # increase the count of each bigram
for bigram, count in counter.items():  # use counter.iteritems() on Python 2.x
    if count > 1:  # consider only bigrams with larger count than 1
        print("{} {}: {}".format(bigram[0], bigram[1], count))
```